Cassandra retryPolicy doesn't catch ReadFailure
I created a custom retryPolicy to implement backoff for my Keyspaces cluster.
It works for read timeouts, I do have logs with retry on_read_timeout. But It doesn't retry on ReadFailure, and my understanding is that it should do it thanks to the on_request_error method. But it doesn't and fails immediately with the following error: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message=\\"Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures\\" info={\'consistency\': \'LOCAL_QUORUM\', \'required_responses\': 2, \'received_responses\': 0, \'failures\': 1}
cassandra-driver==3.25.0
cassandra-sigv4==4.0.2
Here is my retry policy:
from cassandra.policies import RetryPolicy

class KeyspacesRetryPolicy(RetryPolicy):
    def __init__(self, RETRY_MAX_ATTEMPTS=5, base_delay=0.5, max_delay=10):
        # retry_num starts at 0
        self.max_retry_num = RETRY_MAX_ATTEMPTS-1
        self.base_delay = base_delay 
        self.max_delay = max_delay

    def __backoff(self, retry_num):
        # exponential backoff delay
        delay = min(self.base_delay * (2 ** (retry_num + 1)), self.max_delay)
        print(f"Backing off for {delay} seconds (retry number {retry_num})")
        time.sleep(delay)

    def on_read_timeout(self, query, consistency, required_responses, received_responses, data_retrieved, retry_num):
        if retry_num <= self.max_retry_num:
            self.__backoff(retry_num)
            print("retry on_read_timeout")
            return self.RETRY, consistency
        else:
            return self.RETHROW, None 

    def on_write_timeout(self, query, consistency, write_type, required_responses, received_responses, retry_num):
        if retry_num <= self.max_retry_num:
            self.__backoff(retry_num)
            print("retry on_write_timeout")
            return self.RETRY, consistency
        else:
            return self.RETHROW, None

    def on_unavailable(self, query, consistency, required_replicas, alive_replicas, retry_num):
        if retry_num <= self.max_retry_num:
            self.__backoff(retry_num)
            print("retry on_unavailable")
            return self.RETRY, consistency
        else:
            return self.RETHROW, None 

    def on_request_error(self, query, consistency, error, retry_num):
        if retry_num <= self.max_retry_num:
            self.__backoff(retry_num)
            print("retry on_request_error")
            return self.RETRY, consistency
        else:
            return self.RETHROW, None


I have the impression that on_request_error is never called
